# Check token validity from startup.cs

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, jwt

I have multiple API's and one of them allow token authentication, the controller of the authentication api generate a token, and what I want is check the validity of this token from the startup.cs of the other API's.

Anyone has an idea how to do it corretly?

Here is my `startup.cs` where I want to check the recieved token:

```
 //Add JWT
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
  options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;})
    .AddJwtBearer(options => {
      options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
      options.MetadataAddress = "http://localhost:50214/api/Authentification/Validate";
      options.SaveToken = true;
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Jwt middleware itself is perfectly happy to perform validation. What you may be interested in doing is reacting to one or more of the *events* that the middleware exposes, such as `OnMessageReceived` (a "raw" way of interacting with the protocol and making modifications) or `OnTokenValidated` (which happens after rather then before validation has occurred).

These are attached to the [`JwtBearerEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerevents?view=aspnetcore-2.1) class which can be accessed from your code via `options.Events`.

Comment: I will try to explain my need.Roughly, I have a microservices architecture and one of the services deals with the authentication. So what I want is, when the other services recieved an http request, then they should appeal the authentication service to check the token validity.